# Angular UI bootstrap accordion open direction

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is there any way of changing the default opening direction of Angular-UI bootstrap accordion component?

I have been looking into `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` and I found that `acoordion-toggle` class is set for accordion template, but I can't found this class anywhere!

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion

I want to open it to the left side, thanks.

Comment: The Angular UI Accordion directive depends on the Collapse directive. I believe you are looking for this code: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/collapse/collapse.js#L13

Comment: This is a good point to start, I will try to change height to width, thank you!

Comment: Just an updated: Angular UI Bootstrap includes an horizontal collapse since version 2.0.0 that could make the trick

Answer (score 0):

this class is in the detective template file. I suggest that you override accordion-toggle in your css files and ensure that this file is the last included

Comment: I like the detective template file. Please dont edit.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with detective template file, can you explain this to me?